# silverlight in vs2008

Tags: silverlight

when i start application in vs2008 it was showing following error
Requested registry access not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue in the beta version of VS2008. Are you running a beta version?

Comment: Which version of Silverlight SDK are you using?

Comment: silverlight2_SDK with silverlight tools for vs2008